# Why I can't call an implemented interface method in normal way?

Tags: java, android

Suppose there's an interface B and a class A:

```
interface B {
    void bb ();
}

public class A {
    ...
    public B B1 = new B() {
        @override
        public void bb() {
            ...
        }
        private void bbb(){ //this looks weird but compiler is ok on it.
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

I need to call the bb() implemented in A in my class X, so I did this:

```
public class X {
    private A a = new A();
    a.B1.bb();
}
```

But in a.B1.bb(); compiler says bb() is defined in an unaccessible class or interface, any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Are you writing `a.B1.bb()` directly in `X`? Or are you writing it in a method in `X`?

Comment: Directly, not in a method.

Comment: You can't just write a method call directly in a class. Write it in a method and call that method from `onCreate` or something.

Comment: You're right, sorry it's in a method, my previous reply is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any packages involved? The interface in your example is declared with default visibility (i.e. the interface is visible only in its own package) and `A` is `public`. If `X` is in a different package than `B` the interface is not visible. Therefore you should mark your interface as `public`.

Comment: Yeah, A and B are in a different package, but being imported in X

Comment: @BobZhu The problem is, that the interface B is not visible in the class X, even if it is imported, because you haven't declared B as public. Defining a method in class A works, because A is public and therefore visible in X and hence you can call a function of A.
In general, if you don't add the 'public' keyword to your class or interface all of its functions will only be visible for classes in the same package, even if the function itself is declared as 'public'.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good comment that explains what happened, thank you, Jannik.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a method in calss A:

```
public void dobb() {
    B1.bb();
}
```

Then call it in my class X, it works!